# MySQL Query to retrieve data from two tables even no data found and unique column in both tables

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two tables.

## Menu

```
+----------------+----------------+
| menu_id        |   menu_desc    |
+----------------+----------------+
| 1              |      menu1     |
| 2              |      menu2     |
| 3              |      menu3     |
| 4              |      menu4     |
| 5              |      menu5     |
+----------------+----------------+
```

## Rights

```
+----------+--------------+---------+
| Role_id  |   menu_id    |  Rights |
+----------+--------------+---------+
| 1        |      1       |     3   |
| 1        |      2       |     3   |
| 1        |      3       |     3   |
+----------+--------------+---------+
```

I want the output something like this,

```
+----------+------------------+------------+-----------+
| menu_id  |      menu_desc   |  Role_id   |   Rights  |
+----------+------------------+------------+-----------+
| 1        |       menu1      |     1      |     3     |
| 2        |       menu2      |     1      |     3     |
| 3        |       menu3      |     1      |     3     |
| 4        |       menu4      |     1      |    null   |
| 5        |       menu5      |     1      |    null   |
+----------+------------------+------------+-----------+
```

Is it possible?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Try with Left Outer Join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives NULL for both Role_id and Rights

```
SELECT Menu.menu_id, Menu.menu_desc, Role.Role_id, Role.Rights
FROM Menu LEFT OUTER JOIN Role ON Menu.menu_id=Role.menu_id
ORDER BY Menu.menu_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use join:

```
select Menu.menu_id, menu_desc, Role_id, Rights.menu_id, Rights.Rights from Menu join Rights on Menu.menu_id=Rights.menu_id;
```

Comment: i got first 3 records only.. need all records to display

Answer (score 0):

try below, if not getting required results then share problem:

```
SELECT m.menu_id, m.menu_desc, r.Role_id, r. Rights FROM Menu m LEFT JOIN `Rights` r ON m.menu_id=r.menu_id order by m.menu_id;
```